# Zone method from time package doesn't return updated timezone if timezone is changed during process execution

Tags: go, timezone

I have written below a simple Go code to get the system timezone. It works fine and returns the system's current timezone. The issue is if I change the timezone in-between process execution then it doesn't return the updated timezone. It returns only the old timezone.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        t := time.Now()
        zone, offset := t.Zone()
        fmt.Println(zone, offset)
        z, _ := t.Zone()
        fmt.Println("timezone", z)
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you "change the timezone in-between process execution"?

Comment: @jub0bs I think he is talking about changing the system timezone in between, program execution

Comment: if however you just need to work with time, independent of the system setting, use UTC; e.g. `t := time.Now().UTC()`.

Comment: @jub0bs This is just one sample program. I am testing this in debug mode by adding a breakpoint and changing the timezone before the next call.  My main program runs as a background process always in memory which collects timezone information on a certain frequency so it fails to get right timezone if user changes system timezone.

Comment: @MrFuppes: My application requirement is to read user current activity data with system current timezone, so i need to read system current timezone. I am reading time in UTC but also want to read system timezone also.

Comment: Ok I think I get it now. The returned UTC offset / zone stays the one that was set when the application was started.

Comment: Yes, correct. it remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

if you have a look at the [source code of the time package](https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo.go), you can find that the **local Location is set once at the start of the application**, by a [`sync.Once`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Once) (or more precisely: when the tz information is obtained by a call to `.get()` for the first time):

```golang
// localLoc is separate so that initLocal can initialize
// it even if a client has changed Local.
var localLoc Location
var localOnce sync.Once

func (l *Location) get() *Location {
    if l == nil {
        return &utcLoc
    }
    if l == &localLoc {
        localOnce.Do(initLocal)
    }
    return l
}
```

Now, `initLocal` is platform-dependent since different platforms handle time zones differently; for example [for Windows](https://golang.org/src/time/zoneinfo_windows.go) you have:

```golang
func initLocal() {
    var i syscall.Timezoneinformation
    if _, err := syscall.GetTimeZoneInformation(&i); err != nil {
        localLoc.name = "UTC"
        return
    }
    initLocalFromTZI(&i)
}
```

From here on, you could work your way through the source code to get an idea how you can implement this for your application. For example on Windows, you could get the UTC offset in minutes by calling the `Bias` and `DaylightBias` fields of the [`syscall.Timezoneinformation`](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/?GOOS=windows#Timezoneinformation) struct.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, @MrFuppes

The issue got resolved by calling Win32 API from Golang. Below is the code snippet.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "syscall"
    "strconv"
    "unicode/utf16"
)

func main() {
    for index := 0; index < 10; index++ {
        now := time.Now()
        timeZone, _ := now.Zone()
        fmt.Println("timezone", timeZone)

        var itz syscall.Timezoneinformation
        if _, err := syscall.GetTimeZoneInformation(&itz); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("GetTimeZoneInformation failed")
        }
        fmt.Println(strconv.Itoa(int(itz.Bias)))

        var newBytes []uint16
        const intBits = 4 + 4*(^uint(0)>>63)
        if intBits == 4 {
            //For 32 bit
            bytes := itz.StandardName
            for i := 0; i < len(bytes); i++ {
                c := bytes[i]
                if c == 0 {
                    break
                }
                newBytes = append(newBytes, c)
            }
        } else if intBits == 8 {
            //For 64 bit
            bytes := itz.StandardName

            for i := 0; ; i++ {
                c := bytes[i]
                if c == 0 || i == 2048 {
                    break
                }
                newBytes = append(newBytes, c)
            }
        }

        tzName := string(utf16.Decode(newBytes))
        fmt.Println("Timezone StandardName: ", tzName)
    }
}
```